# What IAM roles are needed for deploying to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to give permissions to a third party to make deployments to Firebase Hosting on a project I have set up. I explored the IAM permissions available in the GCP console, and the only half-related role seems to be the `Firebase Rules System`, however that didn't allow the user to deploy to hosting. While `Project Editor` would probably work, I don't want to give them that much authority, as they could launch other Firebase products at my expense.

What IAM roles should I add to allow a user to deploy to Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (2018-11-12)**: Firebase seems to have added more granular permission settings with their October 28, 2018 release:

> The Firebase console now offers predefined Firebase roles. These new roles enable more granular access than the primitive Owner/Editor/Viewer roles. To edit member access for your project, visit the [Firebase console Users and permissions page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/iam). For more information on roles, see [Manage project access with Firebase IAM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview).

Digging deeper, I found these IAM entries related to hosting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#hosting

---

**Original answer:**

I asked Firebase support and the following was their reply:

> To be able to deploy hosting app your developer must be either an
>   Owner or Editor. So in your case, lowest privilege that you can give
>   is Editor because currently role-based access restriction for Static
>   Hosting is unavailable. We're aware that many developers, such as
>   yourself, would like more extensive and granular control for
>   permissions. We're exploring potential solutions, but I can't share
>   any details or timelines at this time.
>
> Keep an eye out on our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for any further updates.

Comment: Would you please give an update on this question if this changes? In my opinion it would also be great to have a dedicated role for deployments, as we are having the same situation where a 3rd party should be able to deploy an app, but not have access to anything else as the interfaces are described and the rest of the customers data/ gcp-project should not be visible or even changeable

Comment: @user2122552 Yeah, it seems it's now supported, although I haven't checked the functionality myself (I migrated away from Firebase after a hosting outage took my company's site down for hours). The answer has been updated with the new info.