# Proper permission for Cloud Build to deploy to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Permissions recommended for the Cloud Build service account in the [official Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#required_iam_permissions) and the [Firebase CLI community builder docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/firebase#with-iam-roles) are insufficient:

> 3. In the permissions table, locate the email ending with @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, and click on the pencil icon.
> 4. Add `Cloud Build Service Account`, `Firebase Admin` and `API Keys Admin roles`.

I still get the following error in Cloud Build when I do `firebase deploy`:

> Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission

What I've tried is different Firebase IAM roles, `Editor`, and `Owner`. So far only the `Owner` role works. That is way too much privilege for a Cloud Build service account, and violates the least-privilege model.

Everything is in the same Google Cloud project.

Anyone know how to troubleshoot this? Or know which role/permission is missing?

Comment: What specific Firebase services are you deploying? Different permissions are needed depending on which. If Cloud Functions, you also need to add the `Cloud Functions Admin` role.

Comment: So far just Firebase Hosting, but it is good to know for functions we need `Cloud Functions Admin`. I tried adding `Firebase Hosting Admin` and it still does not work (I think `Firebase Admin` covered it anyways).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What IAM roles are needed for deploying to Firebase Hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381154/what-iam-roles-are-needed-for-deploying-to-firebase-hosting)

Comment: @DenisT. unfortunately I don't think it does. I've tried the `Firebase Hosting Admin` role which includes the permissions listed on the site and it still does not work. It's possible Firebase did a release and broke their roles.

Comment: It seems like there may be an accidental permission expansion happening somewhere. This might be a bug in Firebase Hosting -- can you please [file a bug](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) and mention that Michael Bleigh routed you to do so?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I had already filed a ticket. I just sent a follow up email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** seems like it was "an accidental permission expansion" that has been corrected.

I am able restrict the roles to:

1. `Cloud Build Service Account`
2. `Firebase Admin`
3. `API Keys Admin`

Answer (score 1):

For our project (which uses Firestore, Functions, Hosting, and Storage extensively) here is the list we came up with. Critically I wanted to avoid "Firebase Admin" because I did not want this service account to have access to read/write my Firestore data:

- Artifact Registry Administrator
- Cloud Build Service Account
- Cloud Datastore Index Admin
- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud RuntimeConfig Admin
- Cloud Scheduler Admin
- Firebase Hosting Admin
- Firebase Rules Admin
- Pub/Sub Admin
- Service Account User