# How can I authorize Cloud Build to deploy to Firebase Hosting in a different project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build, google-iam

I have GCP project `A` and Firebase project `B` (in a separate GCP project). I'm trying to use Cloud Build in `A` to build a web app and deploy it to Firebase Hosting in `B`.

In `B`'s IAM page, I have granted `A`'s `<id>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` service account the `API Keys Admin`, `Firebase Admin`, and `Service Account User` roles as described in e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676357/proper-permission-for-cloud-build-to-deploy-to-firebase).

The final step in the Cloud Build config used by `A` is the following:

```yaml
  - id: firebase_deploy
    name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        firebase use $_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
        firebase target:apply hosting prod $_FIREBASE_HOSTING_TARGET
        firebase deploy --project=$_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID --only=hosting,firestore:rules
```

I set the `_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID` substitution variable to `B` and the `_FIREBASE_HOSTING_TARGET` variable to a Hosting alias that I use for the site.

When I trigger a build, it fails with the following error:

```
...
Step #3 - "firebase_deploy": Error: Invalid project selection, please verify project B exists and you have access.
Step #3 - "firebase_deploy":
Step #3 - "firebase_deploy": Error: Must have an active project to set deploy targets. Try firebase use --add
Step #3 - "firebase_deploy":
Step #3 - "firebase_deploy": Error: Failed to get Firebase project B. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.
Finished Step #3 - "firebase_deploy"
```

I suspect that the problem may be that I'm not running the Firebase CLI's extra login step first. To do that, it seems that I would need to run `firebase login:ci` locally to generate a token and then pass it via the `FIREBASE_TOKEN` environment variable [as described in the docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems), but the permissions associated with the token appear to be much broader than needed:

[image: screenshot from token generation page]

The build process should only have access to Firebase project `B`, rather than "all my Firebase data and settings" and "my Google Cloud data".

1. Is there any way to avoid needing to run `firebase login` here? It seems like the service account should already have sufficient access to deploy to Firebase Hosting.
2. If I need to run `firebase login`, is there any way to create a token with a limited scope (assuming that my understanding of the default scope is correct)?

(I've also given `B`'s service account the `Cloud Functions Developer` role in `A` and am able to successfully run `gcloud --project=$_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID functions deploy ...` in a different build config. I'm also using a Cloud Build config similar to the one described above to deploy to Firebase Hosting in the same GCP project, so I suspect that `firebase login` isn't necessary in all cases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an approach that lets project `A`'s Cloud Build service account deploy to `B` without needing excessive permissions.

First, I created a service account named `deploy` under `B` and granted it the `Firebase Hosting Admin`, `Firebase Rules Admin`, and `Cloud Datastore Index Admin` roles. (I'm not sure whether the Datastore role is needed, but the console showed it as being used recently so I left it.)

Next, I generated a JSON key for the new service account, pasted it (including newlines and double-quotes) as a substitution variable named `_DEPLOY_CREDENTIALS`, and updated the build step to copy it to the environment:

```yaml
 - id: firebase_deploy
    name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
    entrypoint: bash
    args: ['-e', '--', 'build/deploy_hosting.sh']
    env:
      - DEPLOY_CREDENTIALS=$_DEPLOY_CREDENTIALS
      - FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
      - FIREBASE_HOSTING_TARGET=$_FIREBASE_HOSTING_TARGET
```

In `deploy_hosting.sh`, I write the credentials to a temporary file and then pass them to the `firebase` command via the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e
    
CREDS=$(mktemp -t creds.json.XXXXXXXXXX)
printenv DEPLOY_CREDENTIALS >"$CREDS"
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$CREDS
      
firebase --debug use "$FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"
firebase target:apply hosting prod "$FIREBASE_HOSTING_TARGET"
firebase deploy --project="$FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID" --only=hosting,firestore:rules
```

I created a separate shell script for the step since I ran into problems with quotes being stripped from the credentials when writing them directly from the build step. It would likely be possible to store the credentials in [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) instead, but that felt like overkill for my use case.

I'm still curious about whether there's a way to let `A`'s service account deploy to `B` without using a service account in `B` while running the `firebase` executable.